# No such VFS error sqlite ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am getting **"No Such VFS"** error message while trying to open database. Below is the code i used to open

```
- (sqlite3 *) getNewConnection
{
    sqlite3 *newconnection;

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasename.sqlite"];

        if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newconnection) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Succesfully opened");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"DB Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(newconnection));
        }

    return newconnection;
}
```

Here is the error message i got printed in console

" no such vfs:"

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: I have used this pattern many times and have not seen this error. Is this "no such vfs" seen in conjunction with your `DB Error` message? Are you seeing this on the device or simulator? Is this literally all that there is in your code? (e.g., absolutely no other `sqlite3` calls before `sqlite3_open`? no changes to the filename or anything else?) Are you using the standard SQLite library or are you using any third party frameworks/libraries?

Comment: I am not getting this error very often. Some times I used to see this error while i remove the app and try to re run the app. It happens both on device and simulator also. I am using standard libSqlite3 library for DB actions, but i am using third party libraries for other purposes like downloading assets. I am sure i am not making any calls before sqlite open.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for it, too. I see periodic messages on the console, but since the `sqlite3_xxx` calls don't fail, I've never paid too much attention to them. I don't recall seeing the "no such VFS" warning, though (it's generally a result of incorrect call to `sqlite3_open_v2`, which you're not doing). Anyway, that's why I ask whether you see your SQLite call actually fail (i.e. you see your `DB Error` message), or whether it's just an informational message.